# How to remove empty array from payload

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio

Below are the details-

My objective is to remove all keys having empty array, and all empty objects.

Sample Input

```
{
    "Type": "User",
    "id": "12345",
    "meta": {
        "userInfo": [],
        "lastUpdated": "2019-05-28T19:29:36"
    },
    "Relatioship": [{
        "type": {
            "coding": [{
                "system": "xyz"
            }]
        },
        "system": 99004
    }],
    "period": {
        "start": "2010-10-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2010-10-12T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "Contacts": [],
    "Manager": [{
 
        "type": {
            "coding": []
        }
    }],
    "team": [
        []
    ],
    "account": [
        []
    ]
}
```

Is there any common function that can be used on any type of payloads to remove the empty arrays specifically like userInfo[] shouldn't be present in the end response.

Expected Output:

```
{
    "Type": "User",
    "id": "12345",
    "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2019-05-28T19:29:36"
    },
    "Relatioship": [{
        "type": {
            "coding": [{
                "system": "xyz"
            }]
        },
        "system": 99004
    }],
    "period": {
        "start": "2010-10-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2010-10-12T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you are not only want to remove empty arrays but also the keys that get empty because of removing the arrays. The method from this [KB article](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-ignore-empty-fields-objects-and-arrays-using-Dataweave) is very flexible and can be used for this or other use cases. I encapsulated in a function for easier reuse.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun treeFilter(value: Any, predicate: (value:Any) -> Boolean) =
    value  match {
            case object is Object ->  do {
               object mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
                    (key): treeFilter(value, predicate)
                )
                filterObject ((value, key, index) -> predicate(value))
            }
            case array is Array -> do {
                    array map ((item, index) -> treeFilter(item, predicate))
                                         filter ((item, index) -> predicate(item))                 
            }
            else -> $
    }

fun filterEmpty(value: Any) = 
    treeFilter (value, (value) -> 
    value match {
        case v is Array| Object | Null | "" -> !isEmpty(v)
        else -> true
    })

---
filterEmpty(payload)
```

Output:

```json
{
  "Type": "User",
  "id": "12345",
  "meta": {
    "lastUpdated": "2019-05-28T19:29:36"
  },
  "Relatioship": [
    {
      "type": {
        "coding": [
          {
            "system": "xyz"
          }
        ]
      },
      "system": 99004
    }
  ],
  "period": {
    "start": "2010-10-12T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2010-10-12T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
}
```