# How to print a tag in mule 4 only if exists a value?

Tags: mule4, anypoint-studio

I have this code for print a json result, the problem is that I need only tags with data.

Example :

```
'dateOfBirth':
if(payload.ns0#Report_Data.ns0#Report_Entry.ns0#dateOfBirth != null)
(payload.ns0#Report_Data.ns0#Report_Entry.ns0#dateOfBirth [0 to 9] as Mydate)
 else "",
```

the result is this :
{   **"dateOfBirth": "",**
"hireDate": "2013-12-13"
}

I try change the sentence, actuallty I use mule 4 , but I wish to expect only one value if doesn´t exist value or is null.

{   **"dateOfBirth": "",** ----> not print
"hireDate": "2013-12-13"
}

Comment: You should create a minimal example to explain the problem. It is hard to say exactly what you need. Do you mean if the first value is null then omit all others?

Comment: My expectation is if my data dateOfbirth is null or empty only print the other variable : {"dateOfBirth": "", ----> shouldn´t here because is "" 
    "hireDate": "2013-12-13"
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove empty array from payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76408805/how-to-remove-empty-array-from-payload). This kind of question was asked many times before. Just reuse the script to remove empty values from an existing answer like the one I shared. Feel free to upvote the original answer.

Comment: To ignore null fields in your output, you can use output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere".

Comment: @jarus you could post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this. One basic approach is to set the "skipNullOn" attribute to "everywhere" in the output directive. This will skip all key-value pairs that have a null value. To use this method, format the payload so that it replies with a null value after mapping. This can then be handled by "skipNullOn". Note that this method will only work on null values and not on empty values (i.e., "").

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
payload
```

Input

```
{
    "dateOfBirth": null,
    "hireDate": "2013-12-13" 
}
```

Output

```
{
  "hireDate": "2013-12-13"
}
```

However, if you want to exclude both null and empty values, you can apply "filterObject" with an empty check. This will ensure that only key-value pairs with non-null and non-empty values are included in the output.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json 
---
payload filterObject ((value, key, index) -> ! isEmpty(value))
```

Input

```
{
    "dateOfBirth": "",
    "hireDate": "2013-12-13" 
}
```

Output

```
{
  "hireDate": "2013-12-13"
}
```

To apply this method for a specific key-value pair when the value is null:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json 
---
{ 
    ("dateOfBirth": payload.dateOfBirth) if ! isEmpty(payload.dateOfBirth), 
    "hireDate": payload.hireDate
}
```

Input

```
{
    "dateOfBirth": null,
    "hireDate": "2013-12-13" 
}
```

Output

```
{
  "hireDate": "2013-12-13"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jarus, well I have a success in this point, I use this :           
  (if(payload.dateOfBirth != null)
'dateOfBirth': (payload.ns0#Report_Data.ns0#Report_Entry.ns0#dateOfBirth [0 to 9] as Mydate)
 else {}) but this work well too                                                                        ("dateOfBirth": payload.dateOfBirth) if ! isEmpty(payload.dateOfBirth), 
    "hireDate": payload.hireDate     . Thanks.